# How to get Facebook user id from Auth0-Lock SSO Authentication

Tags: auth0, auth0-lock

I'm using Auth0-Lock for authenticating a user. But it seems that the response data from Auth0 did not include Facebook `user_id`. I want to get `user_id` because I need it to show user's profile URL in my app, like this: `www.facebook.com/{user_id}`.

```
{
"sub": "facebook|1613270415401150",
"given_name": "Steve",
"family_name": "Giáp",
"nickname": "hgbk.it",
"name": "Steve Giáp",
"picture": "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/1613270415401150/picture?width=720",
"gender": "male",
"locale": "en-GB",
"updated_at": "2018-10-09T04:25:12.921Z"
}
```

The Id from `sub` or `picture` are not related to `user_id`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `user_id` that Auth0 uses is the id that is provided by the identity provider and in the case of Facebook they are now app-scoped. Therefore, the `user_id` is not the user id of the user, but rather an identifier for the user for this specific application. As per [Facebook docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v3.1/user) `The id of this person's user account. This ID is unique to each app and cannot be used across different apps.` This is the `id` that Auth0 uses as the `user_id`, following the pipe, e.g. `facebook|<id from Facebook>`. I believe you used to be able to use that `id` to see a person's public profile, but Facebook has since deprecated providing the `username`.